Как установить три ос на ноутбук Dell latitude e5440?
У меня есть два диска: первый SSD. там стоит Windows 10, и ещё есть один жесткий который разделен на 4 раздела - 2 - под Ubuntu 20.04 , один - под все ос, а последний - для Windows 7. Когда установка windows 7 проходит и она запускаеться - зависает на логотипе, любые сборки качал - ничего оказываеится надо включить Legacy че то там но потом виндовс 10 не запускаеться, подскажите как мне все это установить что бы работало.

Если у кого то такая же самая проблема - обновляйте биос! А потом в настройки биос оффайте секюрити бут, потом включайте легаси бут фор легаси ромс, а потом там должно бить че то там типу "Uefi" или "Legacy" И нажмите на юефи, у меня к примеру все установилось!
